# I/O redirection in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, io-redirection

Is it possible to use I/O redirection in Eclipse?

I want to redirect standard input/output on the command line like `java MyProgram <input.txt >output.txt`, but I can't seem to get it to work in Eclipse. I tried including the <'s as part of the program arguments, which was ignored, and also in the VM arguments, which just threw up a class not found error. How can I do this?

Comment: Actually there is a solution, but you may be already gone ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To truly redirect both, the simplest way is still to define your program as an external script

```
 "java %1 %2 %3 %4 < %5 > %6"
```

(adapt the number of parameters to your particular program)

In the Run menu, click 'External Tools.../Open External Tools Dialog" and define an external launch configuration in which you will specify both the arguments and the input and output file.

---

It is not an ideal solution though, as you cannot debug *directly* your code (with a "debug" launcher configuration).
Instead you have to remote debug it (add '`-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000`' in your generic Java launcher script)

Once you have launched your external tool, launch a remote debug session through the "debug launcher 'Remote Java Application'" section:

[image: Remote Debug, after blog.jmwyttenbach.net/wp-content/uploads/2007/10/eclipseremotedebug.jpg]

Answer (score 12):

You can redirect *output* using the Run dialog, Common tab, "Standard Input and Output" section.

However, it doesn't look like you can redirect *input* as far as I can tell (and as far as [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188547/eclipse-reading-stdin-system-in-from-a-file/188654) can tell, too).

How much control do you have over your application? If you don't mind a bit of a hack, you could have a couple of properties or command line arguments to determine the appropriate files, and use `System.setOut` and `System.setIn` accordingly. It *is* a bit of a hack though...

Comment: Thats what I was just about to reply to say... Yeah, It looks like its not possible to do it cleanly in eclipse, so i'll just keep a terminal open I suppose. Thanks