# Disable Logger in a .jar java library

Tags: java, xml, logging, spring-boot

How to disable logger (print output) of a java library (jar) used in a java program ?

For example i use the jar `joda-time-2.8.2.jar`

What should I put in my logback.xml file to disable the console output of the jar

***logback.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <Target>System.out</Target>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="com.paper.white" additivity="false" level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </logger>
    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create a logger for `org.joda.time` and set the level to `OFF`.

```
<logger name="org.joda.time" level="OFF" >
    <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: not work i have the log. When i decompile my jar i saw a `System.out.println(...);` it's possible to desactivate ?

Comment: you can only 'redirect' **all** console output. see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882487/disable-system-out-for-speed-in-java

Comment: where i define this ? i create a new class

Comment: You should call `System.setOut(...)` as early as possible in your code. But beware, all your *logback* configuration will be moot, since you only have a *stdout* appender (which will be redirected as well).'
So, if this is just a cosmetic thing and the additional log lines do not have a performance impact or clutter your logs, I wouldn't go down this road.