# Eclipse: program arguments

Tags: eclipse

I have a program (called `myprogram`) that I build with Eclipse; I can start it from the command line as follows:

```
myprogram < myinifile
```

As you can you see, I pass as input the ini file "myinifile".

My question is how to pass it the input file when launching the program from within Eclipse using the Run command.

I know I can specify program arguments in *Run / Run configurations / Tab: Arguments* but how do I specify an input file?

```
"myinifile" --> doesn't work
"< myinifile" --> doesn't work either
```

Comment: This should help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799250/i-o-redirection-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can configure arguments in `Run Configurations`. In `Commons` tab you can redirect output in "Standard Input and Output" section. But, it appears there is no option to redirect input.

Read more here - [Bug 155411 - [launch] Need a way to assign stdin to a file from Run Dialog](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=155411)

If you have control over the application and can modify it, see [Eclipse reading stdin (System.in) from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/188547/1048330) for some options.