# Eclipse Oxygen: Reading input from a file with <, Run configuration

Tags: eclipse

So in the terminal, I can run my program with

> ./letter --stack -b ship -e shot -c --output W < input.txt > output.txt

How do I achieve the same functionality in Eclipse? I've figured out how to do `--stack -b ship -e shot -c --output W` by going to the arguments tab under Run configuration.

I've looked online and seen a lot of posts about using the Common tab to input and output redirection but I can't get it working. When I check only the input file, it doesn't work and the Debug perspective shows it's stuck somewhere trying to read from a stream. When I check allocate console and input file, then it gets stuck on user input (aka I can manually type stuff) in the console.

So how do I get `< input.txt` and by extension `> output.txt` working?

Comment: 'Standard Input and Output' section on 'Common' tab. Check 'Input' and browse to your file

Comment: Already did that as noted in the question.

Comment: check second answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188547/eclipse-reading-stdin-system-in-from-a-file/188654

Comment: What part of the second answer are you talking about? The first half is outdated. The second half complete changes the program interface.

Comment: `${resource_loc:/MyProject/file}` does not work for you?

Comment: As a parameter within Input file, nope.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799250/i-o-redirection-in-eclipse

Comment: Those are outdated posts. Functionality was added in Eclipse Mars.

Comment: I don't think bash redirection will ever work since Eclipse is not using bash to run configurations. Wrap your command in a shell script an run it with `${resource_loc:/MyProject/input.txt} ${resource_loc:/MyProject/output.txt}` in the arguments.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can. Otherwise, why would Eclipse implement the input and output file fields?

Comment: Agree, those fields are for a reason, what I meant is that `< >` redirectors are not usable as in a console or a bash script. I looked for variables that represent those fields and they are not defined in eclipse.

Comment: Oh yes, I definitely agree. I think the input and output fields is eclipse's way of getting around that. Unfortunately, I can't get those fields working, which is what my original question is about.

Comment: did you consider using a wrapper script?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what this question is asking.