# Setting up Eclipse to call my program with the following argument " < fileName.txt"

Tags: c, eclipse, unix

I am developing a application that reads from the stdin and does some computations on the data. I have currently set on Eclipse's Program's Arguments the following string:

```
< "input.txt"
```

where `input.txt` is the file I want to read from, but it doesn't seem to be working, as with the following code only "abc" is being printed:

```
char c;
printf("abc\n");
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse reading stdin (System.in) from a file.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188547/eclipse-reading-stdin-system-in-from-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

The `<` symbol is not a program argument, its a shell operator - it only works in a shell that understands it as part of parsing a command line.

Apparently, Eclipse doesn't use a shell to start up a Java programs and it doesn't itself process shell operators like `<` for starting up.  I'll bet if you printed the command arguments in your program, you'd see `<` and `input.txt`.  A shell would have processed them and not passed them to the program.

Unfortunately, I don't see anything in my version of Eclipse that suggests how to redirect the standard input to come from a file.