# get user input through file to java program in eclipseIDE

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line

In command prompt 
i usually give input to java program as follows

c:/> java Myprogram < in.txt

this in.txt have input for the Myprogram class

but i cannot do the same in eclipse

i have give the parameter in program arguments in run configuration as

< in.txt

no error is coming.
simply the program ask for the input

what should i do.

Answer (score 1):

The `<` symbol is something understood and interpreted by the command line. You can't use that in Eclipse.

You Have a look at the answer to this question:

- [Eclipse reading stdin (System.in) from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188547/eclipse-reading-stdin-system-in-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

in your main Method, you can get the parameters via the String array the main method has.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    for(int i = 0; i <args.length; i++)
        System.out.println(args[i]);
}
```